# Django- settting initial condition of ForeignKey/ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, webforms, conditional-statements

My app has a form which is completed and submitted by the user to submit an entry to the database.
I have 3 forms.ModelChoiceFields based off models.ForeignKey.
I am setting them to intial values through my view, and 2 of them work as intended.
However, the 3rd dropdown uses a 2 word meta definition as the display, first and last name. I can't seem to figure out how to initially populate the form by calling 2 words.

`#in views.py 

form = EmployeeForm(initial={'facility':'None'  # this works

         'supervisor':'_ None'} # does not work`

For facility, None is a string entry in the db, not the None "value"
For supervisor,  _ None is a first/last name entry in db

`#part of class Facility

def __ unicode__ (self): #had to added spaces for _ _ to show here

return self.fac_name`

`#part of class Supervisor

def __ unicode__ (self): #same syntax note as above

    return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`

The drop downs populate and submit correctly- the only problem I have is setting the initial value for the supervisor. How do I call in the initial value with two names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the instance with the correct first/last name as initial value:

```
default_supervisor = Supervisor.objects.get(first_name='_', last_name='None')
form = EmployeeForm(inital={'supervisior': default_supervisor})
```

Comment: Thanks! Knowing this now, I may just try to use 1 word names for foreignkey drop-down forms, less code!

Comment: I do not know what you're exactly doing, but normally its more recommendable to use `None` instead of an existing db entry!

Comment: Well I was entering 'none' (string value) db entries because at the time the fields were required even though (I thought) that they shouldnt be.  Well, as I found out, SQLite can't update column attributes, so they were required because of my original model parameters. Fortunatly, since I didn't have any real data in there I just rebuilt the db to the new model and it fixed many of the the other problems I was having with fields that I had set to null=blank=true but were still faulting when None. Lesson learned.